# sql delete lock

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I execute a query in JDBC

```
delete * from mytable where ...
```

I got:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
```

I have about 200k records in the table.
how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can happen when deleting a large # of rows in mysql/innodb, the suggested workaround is to increase your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` until it works.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15667

Answer (score 0):

I just Googled this up.  Assuming you're using MySQL, increase your innodb_buffer_pool_size if you have a default size set.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/